# Stop propagation of a JavaScript event defined using Attributes in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have defined the client-side click event for a link in the code-behind of an ASP.Net page. This code is in VB.Net as below and it uses `Attributes` collection of link control to add this client-side event. This event is executing as expected, but I cannot get a handle on the `event' argument for stopping event propgation.

**Question**

How can I access the `event` argument so that the `stopPropagation` method can be called to prevent the click event of a parent div from firing?

```
Dim link As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton = DirectCast(sender,
                                                      System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)

       link.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OnEmployeeClick('" & 
       dataRowItem("EmployeeId").ToString() & "','" & link.ClientID & "'); 
       return false; ")
```

**UPDATE 1**

As suggested by dandavis, I simply used the automatically available `event` argument, and it worked. I added new code of `event.stopPropagation();` just before the `OnEmployeeClick` method call in the `onclick` definition in code-behind.

```
   Dim link As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton = DirectCast(sender,
                                                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)

   link.Attributes.Add("onclick", "event.stopPropagation();OnEmployeeClick('" & 
   dataRowItem("EmployeeId").ToString() & "','" & link.ClientID & "'); 
   return false; ")
```

Comment: as `event` usually (browsers insert the name in inline events for you), or as `arguments[0]` always

Comment: @dandavis, You mean the `event` argument is automatically available? if yes, is this a cross-browser thing?

Comment: Can you write this as an answer?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I tried `'event' in my code and it works. Please post this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers automatically insert a formal parameter to inline events (those defined in HTML attributes), `event`.

that means that

```
<div onclick=alert(event.type)> Test </div>
```

should alert "click" when clicked, getting that event type string from the "magic" `event` parameter.

tested in FF, Ch, IE9.

see live demo to test your own browser for compat: http://pagedemos.com/s87ynjsgc7pe

Comment: I used `event.stopPropagation()` as explained in UPDATE 1. It works.